# Sending null variable in my backend, am I doing it wrong of my frontend?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to send a variable from my angular frontend to my sprinboot backend. But the value of the variable is reaching null. I've tried several approaches and it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Springboot JAVA**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/product")

@RequestMapping(value = "v2/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity <Page<ComponentDTO>> search(Long id, Pageable pageable) throws Exception {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.service.search(id, pageable), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Service Typescript**

```
PATH = '/server/api/product';

list(id: number): Observable<EntityBase<Component>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<EntityBase<Component>>(`${this.PATH}/v2/${id}`);
}
```

**tracktrace**

*ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY.*

Comment: Your question is **self contradictory**.  The title says you are sending a `null` to the backend, the text you are sending zero, and the error message implies it is sending something else.  (The problem is the type rather than the value.)  Please do some research (i.e. debugging!) to find out what you are really sending to the backend and then update your question.  Otherwise, you will probably only get random guesses for answers.

Comment: The question is correct.

The backend is receiving null from the frontend.
And that is exactly the error it presents.

The database cannot receive null, only number.
So the question remains the same, is the form being done the right one?

Comment: So what does *"the value of the variable is reaching zero."* really means then?  And why are you asking where the problem is when you >know< where it is?

Comment: I changed zero to null.

The question is whether the process of sending the frontend to the backend is going on correctly.

I'm missing something and I'm not solving it

Comment: Well you should probably look at the actual request URLs in the GET requests.  That will allow you to work out if the problem is that the frontend is creating incorrect requests, or the backend is mishandling correct requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple thing that is incorrect in your code:

1. Add the backslash in your endpoint value.
2. Add @PathVariable annotation to the ID field.
3. You are using pagination incorrectly.

Bellow example without pagination, if you want yo add pagination, try to send page number as query param in the URL and use @RequestParam annotation to achieve this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity <Page<ComponentDTO>> search(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception {
```

Hint: Use @GetMapping instead.

Comment: This solution is ideal. I learned new things from your answer. And question completed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try to change this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "v2/{id}",
```

to the this please:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/{id}",
```

add / before v2

Comment: I already did it that way but it didn't work